# Sealing a laminate kitchen worktop

Tags: kitchen-counters

My kitchen laminate worktop easily stains (particularly tea stains) and has started to lift at a joint again. Can I apply some varnish to make it more repellent to tea stains and water or should I put adhesive over the top of it?

Comment: Why would you think adhesive would be good in this instance? What is the laminate made of? Mica? Mica is not actually a 'solid', it has pores. If it's breathable enough that such as tea can stain it, I'd be worried though. Turmeric, yes, tea no.

Comment: Most plastic laminates would not do well with a varnish. have you considered replacing the laminate? It's not as difficult as you may think, especially if you install a wooden accent edge in which to route a profile.

Comment: I would recommend a clear epoxy or acrylic over varnish.

Comment: At the bare minimum, provide us a picture of the laminate and where it's peeling up.

Answer (score 0):

Use contact cement to re-glue the seam and let dry weighted for a day. Then coat the entire countertop with a good two part colored epoxy with the color/s of your choice.